# compute mean of selected columns in a list of sf objects and store the values in a data frame

Tags: r, spatial, r-sf

Let's say I have a list of `sf` objects, and I would like to compute the mean of selected columns. Afterwards, I would like to store these values in separate columns in a new data frame. The sample data can downloaded from [here](https://app.box.com/s/kizi9f6tn3ce2kpzc6jvs0mu9x38k52o). Below is what I have done so far. How can this be fixed?

```
 # Now make a list of two sample shapefiles "a" and "b"
myfiles = list.files(path = "~",
                     pattern=".shp$", full.names = TRUE)

# Read each shapefile and return a list of sf objects
listOfShp = lapply(myfiles, st_read)
 
# First make an empty df
time.series = data.frame()
# Start a loop
for (i in listOfShp){
  time.series$Mean.Z = data.frame(mean(i$z)) 
  time.series$Intensity.mean = data.frame(mean(i$V4))
}


Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Mean.Z", value = list(mean.i.z. = -4.19655105979791)) : 
  replacement has 1 row, data has 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to assign a data frame to be an entry instead of a value. What you probably want is something like this:

```
time.series <-
  listOfShp %>%
  purrr::map_df(
    function(df_) {
      data.frame(
        Mean.Z = mean(df_$z),
        Intensity.mean = mean(df_$V4)
      )
    }
  )
```

This solution iterates over the listOfShp. For each shapefile dataframe in the list, it applies the function which creates a dataframe with two columns. After it as created a dataframe for each element in the list, it binds them together into a single dataframe.

An even more elegant solution that carries along the file names might be:

```
# Function that takes as an input a file name and outputs some facts about the
# dataframe:
describe_shapefile <- function(shp_path) {
  sf_df <- st_read(shp_path) %>%
    st_set_geometry(NULL)
  mean_z = mean(sf_df$z)
  int_mean = mean(sf_df$V4)
  data.frame(
    filename = shp_path,
    Mean.Z = mean_z,
    Intensity.mean = int_mean
  )
}

# Apply the function to each file in the list
myfiles %>%
  purrr::map_df(describe_shapefile)
```

Comment: This returns an error Error in `[[<-`(`*tmp*`, i, value = data.frame(Mean.Z = mean(i$z), Intensity.mean = mean(i$V4))) : 
  invalid subscript type 'list'

Comment: Ah, my error. Modified the above code to fix this. I was originally trying to use i as the index of the list. I just replaced it with a fully tidy solution using purrr from the tidyvers.

Comment: On a separate note, it looks like your third shapefile doesn't have all of the columns that your first two do.

Comment: Yes the third file is just the study area boundary polygon and is not is needed in this case. And thank you, the code works fine now. I just had to store myfiles %>%
  purrr::map_df(describe_shapefile) in a variable to store the new data frame in the global environment.